# Android touch screen size

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk

I would like to get the size of touch screen. For the reason, when I tested this code in the emulator the minimum values of X is 0(Y too, when pressing the 'corner' of the screen). But when I tested the code on a real devices, X shows displays 2000. So I want to read the absolute values of the screen. I think I need to get the 'minimun, maximum'  values of screen. how can I read this value ?

```
main()
{
    int fileno = open("/dev/input/event0",O_RDONLY),num_bytes;
    char ev[50];
    num_bytes=read(fileno,&ev,sizeof(struct input_event));

    if(num_bytes<=0)
    {
          perror("Cannot access");
          exit(FAILURE);
    }
    printf("%d\n",fileno);
    printf("\nNumber of bytes read is %d\n string is%s\n",num_bytes,ev);
    close(fileno);
}
```

Comment: @HareshChaudhary How can i 'accept' for an answers?

Comment: you can check the checkbox shown below the upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

This will tell you the real size of your screen in pixels, but you'll still need to account for density as well as action bar or title bar in figuring your actuall workable area.